# Basic: Sequence of random variables and CLT

Tags: probability-limit-theorems

I've started reading about Limit Theorems in Probabilities.The chapter starts by saying, let's think of a sequence $S_n = X_1+X_2+X_3$ iid random variables. What is each random variable in the sequence. Is it a value from each r.v. or all the possible values from each r.v.? I understand what a random variable is, it is a function.

For $X_n$ being the height of students, we measured, for n class in a school. What is $X_1$ in a sequence? Is it the average?

Comment: It means that $X_1$ is a random variable, and so is $X_2$, and so is $X_3$ and so on. Moreover, they are independent and identically distributed.

Comment: Thank you for the response, for all these hours, I wasn't thinking that this is a sum. We just add the random variables. I got unstuck. Thank you.